# How to get a URL parameter from a URL with get_query_var?

Tags: query-string

I am trying to get a custom URL parameter from a URL in WordPress.

I add the following code to functions.php:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "token";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

Then on the webpage I write:

```
<?php  $token = get_query_var( 'token', $default = '');  ?>
<h1>Currently Browsing token <?php echo (int) $token; ?> On a 
static front page</h1>
```

and go to the webpage http://www.negovista.com/tokensuccess/?token=xxxxxx

However on the page is only printed

'Currently Browsing token On a static front page' without the xxxxxx

Anyone knows if there is an error in the code?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. Have you debugged the value of `$token` var?

Comment: In the source code of your page, both `<?php $token = get_query_var( 'token', $default = ''); ?>` and `<?php echo (int) $token; ?>` statements are printed as HTML comments (`<!--?php $token = get_query_var( 'token', $default = ''); ?-->` and `<!--?php echo (int) $token; ?-->`). It seems some error in the syntax wihtin your php template file.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer! I think you are right. I am using a front-end editor called cornerstone and it is not possible to just put php-code inside it. I will have to write a shortcode and use that instead.

Comment: @cybmeta Could you explain your comment in an answer in a bit more detail? I'm having the _exact_ same issue. Even copying and pasting the example from the WP Codex yields nothing. My code is `function rj_add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "adminoption";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'rj_add_query_vars_filter' );

echo get_query_var('adminoption', "<h1>NOT SET</h1>");` . My code always returns "NOT SET" my url query is "sometitle/?adminoption=TEST"

Comment: .. also using `echo $_GET["adminoption"];` works fine. I can get that to print out whatever I want. This is in my functions.php file

Comment: @cybmeta is it me you are referring to? If it is then it’s wrong. I did have php tags. The issue was that I was using a front end editor called cornerstone which doesn’t support php

Comment: No, sorry, to @user658182,

Comment: Ok, got a bit confused :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to find a solution with some help from some developers at the theme.co apex forum.

I needed to get two query strings from my URL www.randompage.com/tokensuccess/?token=token&username=username called token and username.

In order to get this I added the following code to the functions.php code:

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "token";
  $vars[] = "username";
  return $vars;
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

get_query_var('token');
get_query_var('username');
```

This inserted the two query strings into the variables token and username

I then added the following code to the page.php file in order to print the values and insert them into the database.

```
<?php if (is_page('tokensuccess')) { if (get_query_var('token')) print "token = $token"; }  ?>

<?php if (is_page('tokensuccess')) { if (get_query_var('username')) print "username = $username"; }  ?>

<?php if (is_page('tokensuccess')) { 
    $token = get_query_var('token');
    $username = get_query_var('username');
    if( $token && $username ){

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 
            'wp_token',
            array( 
                'token' => $token, 
                'username' => $username 
            )
        );
    }
}

?>
```

So now I can send a link with query strings to my customer and automatically get his/her token and name.

Comment: This does not seem to work on admin pages, I put the filter directly in the plugin root file. `get_query_var` returns an empty string.